# applying event handler to dynamic control

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that dynamically places a `commandButton` onto the user form but I can't seem to get the dynamic event handler set up properly: Below shows the code for how I have set up the dynamic button:

```
Set cButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
With cButton
  .Left = 150
  .Top = 0
  .Width = 300
  .Height = 140
End With
```

I have also defined `dim WithEvents cButton as Commandbutton` outside of any sub or procedure and then finally I have the event handler for the dynamic button, which I simply want to output a message for now:

```
Private Sub cButton_Click()
   MsgBox "Dynamic Handler functioning correctly"
End Sub
```

Now that I am able to create event handlers for dynamic events for individual controls, however I am creating multiple controls and they all have the same name `cButton` so how would I be able to create individual event handlers for each of them. Below shows the code that is used to create the multiple controls:

```
If TextBox1 <> vbNullString Then
    For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value


    Set cButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With cButton
            .Left = 150
            .Top = 0
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 140
        End With
  Next i
End IF
```

Comment: I didn't even realize the typo, however when the typo is fixed the issue still remains

Comment: You need to remove this line: `Dim cButton As Control`

Comment: Rory will you look at the comment I have posted under the answer below and see if you can give me some guidance on the matter?

Comment: If the answer below worked for you, you should mark it correct. Your follow up should be moved to a new question, which will be answered more quickly and keep the two topics separate for searching on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cButton` should only be declared once:

```
Dim WithEvents cButton As CommandButton

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set cButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With cButton
      .Left = 150
      .Top = 0
      .Width = 300
      .Height = 140
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cButton_Click()
   MsgBox "Dynamic Handler functioning correctly"
End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Another question on the back of this would be: what if I had a loop that was adding 3 buttons how could I create separate event handlers for each when they will all have the same name `cButton`

Comment: @user3538102 in that case you need a `cButton1`, `cButton2`,... : `Dim WithEvents cButton1 As CommandButton`, `Dim WithEvents cButton2 As CommandButton`, etc... and add a corresponding event handler: `Private Sub cButton1_Click()`,...

Comment: I will edit this question so you can know what I mean because I don't think that is correct or maybe i'm wrong

Comment: If you want them to do different things when clicked you'll need separate variables; if not, use a class and create separate instances of the class that you add to an array/collection/dictionary. There are numerous examples here and elsewhere of that. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks the information! I will have a look into using a class

Comment: How does one dynamically create `Private Sub cButton<x>_Click()` event handlers during runtime?