# VBA userform event code of controls not working when code is static and control created dynamically

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform in excel, with two TextBoxes

And i created the following event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox2 = TextBox1 + 1
End Sub
```

I know i will add two more textboxes dynamically, and i know their names, and i therefore created the following event as well

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    TextBox4 = TextBox3 + 1
End Sub
```

When i run the userform, the first event works, but not the second, even though the name matches.

Can anyone elaborate why it doesnt work like this? and if there is a fix, without having to use class instances?

Comment: Never type event handler signatures by hand; I'd likely write exactly the same answer as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66147762/1188513). Alternatively, double-click on the textbox control in the form designer to create a correctly-formed handler for its default event (that would be the `Change` event for a textbox control). Also consider making your code more explicit: `TextBox4.Text = CLng("0" & TextBox3.Text) + 1` wouldn't rely on implicit default member calls and implicit conversions so much.

Comment: But you said something about controls created dynamically... In such a case the event it is not simple matching with the newly created control name. You must create an event wrapper class and allocate it after creation.

Comment: Also consider *naming* your controls. `QuantityBox` means so much more than `TextBox4`

Comment: @FaneDuru ooooh I completely missed the *dynamic* part

Comment: If the control is dynamic then the only way to handle its events involve a class module, yes. What's so bad about needing class modules? I'd submit this one as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59201151/1188513

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: If theoretically it is not complicated to create a class module and allocate the event using it, it is a little complicated to create it able to be used for all involved text boxes... And a class for each control is possible, but not so elegant.

Comment: If there are not too many controls, you could declare them WithEvents like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381680/applying-event-handler-to-dynamic-control).

Comment: @Brian M Stafford: The idea of "complicated" comes only referring to the events like the OP wants to use. Please, look to the question, from this point of view. If the rule which can be deduced is maintained and the events allocation will be done through an array or a collection the previous versus next object element can be used for adding their (Long) values inside the event code... I am referring to an event handling all situations, not individual ones.

Comment: @BrianMStafford actually *that* is how you'd go about doing this without introducing class modules; it works because the `UserForm` is itself a class. It makes the form's code-behind much more bloated than it needs to be, but satisfies OP's *without having to use class instances* "constraint". It also makes it much simpler to then consume the form's state in the dynamic handlers. I guess it just rubs me the wrong way to do OOP while going out of one's way to avoid leveraging class modules... *they're made for this*.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I generally use the class approach but wanted to mention this as another option (and to satisfy the "no class" constraint).